# How to upload Chef cookbook from current directory?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm moving to a workflow of single git repository per chef cookbook. And I have a fairly recent chefdk. I'd like to be able to upload to chef from within the current git repo without a chef-repo behind it. I'm struggling to see how to do that with knife upload. Any ideas. (I can't move to PolicyFiles yet, but I'd like to setup a piece of the workflow now). Any ideas to just "knife upload" from within a git repo easily, would be helful.

Comment: what have you tried so far? if your chef server is configured - you can just run `knife upload cookbooks` as you have 1 cookbook per git repo. https://docs.chef.io/knife_upload.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a primitive alias "upload" that does `knife cookbook upload ${PWD##*/} -o ..` which will upload the current cookbook.

My directory names match the cookbook name defined in metadata.rb and I only run it from the root of the cookbook so it sufficient for my workflow.

Comment: unfortunately this can run into some very subtle issues. for instance, if you have multiple copies of the same cookbook in subfolders of the parent directory, knife will attempt to upload the first copy of the cookbook that it finds, rather than the one in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) instead. It's part of the chefdk and will also load cookbook dependencies as well.

## Example

```
#
# Generate cookbook
#
$ chef generate cookbook demo
$ cd demo

#
# Upload cookbook using Berkshelf
#
$ berks install
$ berks upload

#
# Check to see cookbooks loaded
#
$ knife cookbook list
demo   0.1.0
```